# Couldn't read file Instance of 'ErrorHandlingFile' even though it exists. Please verify that this file has read permission and try again

Tags: flutter

My Flutter App is not compiling because of this error:

> Couldn't read file Instance of 'ErrorHandlingFile' even though it
>   exists. Please verify that this file has read permission and try again

I tired switching channels and changing versions but nothing has worked yet.

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, v1.13.6, on Mac OS X 10.15.1 19B88, locale de-DE)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.2.1)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.5)
[!] Android Studio
    ✗ Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    ✗ Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
    ✗ Android Studio not found at /Applications/Android/Contents
[!] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2019.2.3)
    ✗ Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    ✗ Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
[✓] VS Code (version 1.36.1)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: `Flutter plugin not installed`, `Dart plugin not installed`, `Android Studio not found at /Applications/Android/Contents` - did you notice these? I assume you need to install those first?

Comment: yeah, that Android Studio, I'm using VS Code, that shouldn't be a problem, right?

Comment: but run apps via SDK, so require plugins

Comment: Have you ever been able to run the app?

Comment: @nopassport1 yes, the Android Studio were always there, I don't even use it and it has always worked. As I said, I use VSCode and it always worked till now

Comment: Found something which might help: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/47933#issuecomment-574088246

Comment: Or this https://stackoverflow.com/q/59310434/8422218

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had the same problem after upgrade to beta channel.

Found that this error message just a top of an iceberg, real problem is in one of your plugins.

Read the discussion in [this issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/48165) to manually debug your application or wait for [fix](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/48104) which will result in an appropriate error message.

If you are lucky - simple `flutter pub upgrade` will solve the issue for your project.

If not, as a hot-fix you can downgrade your flutter version.

Comment: yep, the error was with a package that I removed, now it works fine